# Tilemill labeling graticules

Tags: label, tilemill

Is there a way to have the graticules labels move when you move the map so the grid is always labeled in the current view? I have the following code however, the labels stay at the center of the map.

```
#10mgraticules10 {
  text-name:"[display]";
  text-placement-type: simple;
  text-face-name:@serif_italic;
  text-horizontal-alignment: middle;
  text-vertical-alignment: middle;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to have the graticules labels move when you move the map so the grid is always labeled in the current view?

This isn't possible, by design: TileMill's map view is powered by [tiles, which are stitched together into a final image](https://www.mapbox.com/foundations/how-web-maps-work/). These tiles are images and are not affected by anything beyond basic positioning by your browser.